# Загрузка большого файла на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, файлы

Надо загружать файл размером около 1GB.
Была идея нарезать файл с помощью javascript , передать эту часть ajax`ом и на сервере все склеить. Но как реализовать это не знаю.
Так же можете предложить свои варианты.

Совет поменять значения
     upload_file_size
     post_max_size
и подобное в .htaccess, не рассматриваются.

Comment: да, все правильно, передавайте частями, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Иногда достаточно просто погуглить, вот [решение](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/js/html5-ajax-partial-upload/)

Comment: Решение должно быть описано в самом ответе, а не по ссылке, которая может устареть.